# else if in list comprehension in Python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a string with mixed cases, e.g. "aBcDeF".
I want to upper-case all of the lower-case letters, and for the upper-case letters, only lower-case them if they're the letter 'B'. meaning, I want the result "AbCDEF".
I've tried doing this in a list comprehension:

```
x = [str.upper(char) if char.islower() 
else str.lower(char) if char == "B" for char in "aBcDeF"]
```

- The line breaks are just for reading convenience, in my code they are joined

However, I get the following syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 11
    else str.lower(char) if char == "B" for char in "aBcDeF"]
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've reviewed similar questions, but none provided me the answer.

Comment: `[str.upper(char) if char.islower() else str.lower(char) if char == "B" else char for char in "aBcDeF"]`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with list comprehensions; it's just about correct use of the conditional expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sticking to your spirit of `if-else` list comprehension.

```
print([str.lower(char) if char.isupper() and char =='B' else str.upper(char) for char in "aBcDeF"])
```

prints:

```
['A', 'b', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[char.upper() if char != 'B' else char.lower() for char in "aBcDeF"]
```

Answer (score 4):

@MooingRawr has the best answer for your specific case but if you truly wanted to have multiple `if` statements in your list comprehension you would want to do something like:

```
[x.upper() if x.islower() else x.lower() if x=='B' else x.upper() for x in "aBcDeF"]
```

which might be a bit easier to understand with the parentheses around the second (embedded) `if` statement:

```
[x.upper() if x.islower() else (x.lower() if x=='B' else x.upper()) for x in "aBcDeF"]
```

This isn't ideal in your case though since you have `x.upper()` written twice.

This is essentially equivalent to:

```
new_str = ''

for x in "aBcDeF":
    if x.islower():
        new_str += x.upper()
    elif x == 'B';
        new_str += x.lower()
    else:
        new_str += x.upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Mooingrawr's answer as an example, people may find its construction and understanding a bit easier if you stack the list comprehension.  You can comment within the line if it is stacked.  Should you want to revert it one line, then you can remove the comments and make that one-liner that everyone loves.

```
r = [str.lower(char)                  # Do this
     if char.isupper() and char =='B' # if this
     else str.upper(char)             # else this
     for char in "aBcDeF"]            # using these
print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution,

```
char = "aBcDeF" 

print(char.upper().replace("B", "b"))
```

```
AbCDEF

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MooingRawr, I'd add that you do get a syntax error because you cannot use a conditional expression without an else value.

For example, `a = 3 if blah` raises a SyntaxError but `a = 3 if blah else 4` does not.